# how to add animation to a second view which is inside first view in xcode for ipad using storyboard

Tags: ios, ipad, ios6

In storyboard, in a view controller i've added a scroll view.Inside it another two different views are added & named them as "firstview" & "secondview". When i press add button from "firstview" ,it will show SecondView which is kept as hidden during the initial run. Now i want to display that view by performing some animations. How to solve this?

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.secondview
                  duration:5.0f
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                animations:^{
                            self.secondview.alpha = 1.0f;
              } completion:NULL];
```

tried these but not working

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code if your second view is hidden

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.secondview duration:5.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:^{
        self.secondview.hidden = NO;

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        self.secondview.alpha = 1.0f;

    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

If your **self.secondview** is **hidden** then you need to make it **unhidden** and **set the alpha to 0**. If the secondview is hidden that doesn't mean it's alpha is 0.

So use the same code but instead of make it hidden set the **secondview.alpha = 0;** or in your case make it from the storyboard.